# How many combinations of three numbers using 1, 2, 3, and 4 exist?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If you count (4 4 3) as one combination, you cannot count (4 3 4) as another.

My approach is $\dfrac{4^3}{3!}$, but obviously this does not work. I don't know why it doesn't work, and I don't know how I should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1**: Three distinct numbers.

In this case there are four choices for the first number, three for the second, and two for the third, but each of these $24$ possibilites can be reached in $6$ different orders, so we must divide by $3!$, to get

$$\frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{3!} = 4$$

(alternatively, there are simply $4$ ways to choose the number you leave out)

**Case 2**: Two of the same number, and a third different number.

There are four choices for the first number, and three for the second, for a total of

$$4\cdot 3 = 12$$

**Case 3**: All of the same number.

There are four choices for this number.

---

The total is therefore

$$4 + 12 + 4 = \boxed{20}$$

Comment: Can you explain why \dfrac{4^3}{3} doesn't work?

Comment: How did you get that? I can't really explain why it's wrong unless you tell me your reasoning :)

Comment: 4^3 is the number of sets possible if order mattered. I divide by 3!, because that is the number of arrangements of the three positions.

Comment: btw, thanks for the very clear answer!

Comment: @ffffffffflllllllllll You should only divide by $3!$ if that is the factor by which you overcount *every* arrangement. But your $4^3$ includes arrangements that have fewer than $3!$ multiplicities - for example $(1,1,2)$ has only three arrangements, so dividing that by $3!$ would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by $3!$ means you only count $(1, 2, 3)$ one time, not once for each of the six permutations of $1,2,3$. That is good.

Unfortunately, dividing by $3!$ also means you count only $1/6$
of a combination for $(1,1,1)$.

You may do better if you count triples with all three digits different,
then the combinations with one pair and one digit different,
then the three-of-a-kind combinations.